# Styling input css

Tags: css

I want to make my input from this :

[image]

to this :

[image]

but, I had some trouble, I can't find the keyword on google how to make my input like that, anyone can tell me what should keyword I must input in google to know how to change my input like in second picture, thanks

Comment: add your html css code to help you further on this

Comment: I just wanna know what name of method I must search in google

Comment: It takes more than one keyword. It can get complicated very soon.
Have you consider using a framework like https://materializecss.com ou https://getuikit.com?

Comment: can possible if I not using framework just using a native css?

Comment: Is that your default input type or you have added some CSS to it?

Comment: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/inputs/

Comment: https://w3bits.com/css-floating-labels/

Comment: Krupal Panchal you're input not like my mine but @atul make my problem become solved, but I want appreciate your answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to modify your css like in the given example below, You can modify any element as per your requirements.

```css
form {
  background-color: #fff;
padding: 50px 20px;
}
label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #42C8F1;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ddd;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-color: #fff;
}
input:focus {
outline: none !imporant;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <label>First Name</label> 
   <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
</form>
```

Comment: You're awesome bro, thanks for the code, exactly I just wanna know how to make that style, but you make that code for me, once more I say thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just simple CSS. I have just added simple CSS but you can add as your design requirements.

```css
label{color:blue;font-weight: bold;display: block;}
input[type=text]{border: 0;outline: 0;padding: 5px 0;border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<form>
   <label>First Name</label> 
   <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
</form>
```